# Need to Return first value in an AJAX REST API call

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I'm using REST API and the jQuery AJAX method to pull data from a SharePoint list.  Within the data I'm pulling there is a shipping address which is the same for all the records I'm returning.  I'd like this shipping address to appear only once on the top of my page.  Below is a snippet of the code I have so far.  I've tried all manner of using [0] to try and pull the first item in the array but I always seem to get all items.

So, what's the best way to pull the first item in the array and select a specific field within that item and inject that into the DOM?

```
function pidQuery (storeNum, pidNum){
    var call = $.ajax({
        url: "SiteURL",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"    
            }
        });
        call.done(function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
            var shipLocation = item.ToLocation;
            var shipStreet = item.Street;
            var shipCity = item.City;
            var shipState = item.State;
            $("#shipToLocation").append(shipLocation);
```

UPDATE:  Below is a screenshot of the data.d.results in console.log.  It also shows the portion of my app which is injecting all the results instead of just the first one.  I'd like to just show the value once and not repeat.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a sample of the returned data?

Comment: Added a screen shot of the returned data.

Comment: Just do `$("#shipToLocation").append(data.d.results[0].ToLocation)` outside the `$.each` loop?  You are reading the `ToLocation` value in your `$.each` loop, for every element.

Comment: Thanks, Rocket!  That worked.  I knew it had to be something simple. :)